# Apache Pulsar on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-pulsar

**1. Iam using Apache-pulsar to my kubernetes cluster.when i produce normal text messages , those are consumed by consumer properly. But some how when i produce json data , these data was not consumed by consumer . Is there a way to produce and consume json data as well ?
**

Comment: Please post the code you're using. We need both the consumer and producer code.

Comment: Also, please post an example of a JSON message that is consumed correctly and one that isn't consumed correctly. If they contain sensitive data at all, please obfuscate those parts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.